# Magento 2 : Image upload field in admin form using ui component

Tags: magento2, uicomponent, image-upload

In my admin form I need 2 image upload field. I have added an image upload field using the below code.

mymodule_form.xml

```
<field name="image">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">string</item>
            <item name="source" xsi:type="string">store_logo</item>
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Product Page Label</item>
            <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">fileUploader</item>
            <item name="previewTmpl" xsi:type="string">Magento_Catalog/image-preview</item>
            <item name="elementTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/form/element/uploader/uploader</item>
            <item name="required" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
            <item name="uploaderConfig" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="url" xsi:type="url" path="mymodule/mymodule_storelogo/upload"/>
            </item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</field>
```

And I need one more field like this, but I am getting only one field upon duplicating this code. My doubt is that is it necessary to give the field name as **image** inorder to get image upload field ? Because when I change the field name to any other, it is showing me an error

> Attention
>   The file was not uploaded.

Please Help

Comment: Please see if the referenced question + answer solve your issue.

Comment: @benmarks how can this question be duplicate of  mentioned question? that question is not about ui component form.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to change field name as well as below code:

```
<item name="uploaderConfig" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="url" xsi:type="url" path="mymodule/mymodule_storelogo/upload"/>
</item>
```

For more reference check [this](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/ui-components/ui-secondary-uploader.html)

Comment: Thanks @Prashant.. What all changes need to be done in this code ? Do we need to create new controller action for 2nd image field ?

Comment: Yes you need to create another controller for second image

Comment: Can you describe controller for upload image.

Comment: PLEASE GIVE A CLEARE ANSWER

Comment: May you explain what is path in the code? i dont understand that part. Thanks :)

Comment: @fudu path is upload controller path. which contain file upload process .

Comment: Thanks, i understand it earlier, it go to controller Upload.php :)